# Adding comma and quotes for two columns in sublime on Mac

Tags: sublimetext3

I have data in sublime arranged as follows;

```
353154  0.001039699782
506472  0.02085443362
482346  0.08343533852
439791  0.001349253676
486087  0.9999999476
```

I am trying to put quotes and commas so as to get following output;

```
('353154',  '0.001039699782'),
('506472',  '0.02085443362'),
('482346',  '0.08343533852'),
('439791',  '0.001349253676'),
('486087',  '0.9999999476')
```

I am aware of using `CMD+Shift+L` in order to move cursors right and left. But I need help on how to get the commas and quotes between the two columns. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regex search and replace. Select **`Find → Replace…`** and make sure the `Regular Expression` button (usually looking like this <kbd>*</kbd>) is selected. In the `Find:` field, enter

```regex
([\d\.]+)\s+([\d\.]+)
```

and in the `Replace:` field, enter

```regex
('\1', '\2'),
```

[image: Sublime Text screenshot before]

Hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd> and it will look like this

[image: Sublime Text screenshot after]

See [the demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Ie0Zzg/1), which also explains what each of the capture and replacement groups do.

Please keep in mind that you'll have to delete the final comma `,` if that's not proper syntax for your language of choice.